# How to call action after selecting values from dynamically created dropdown list using struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Here I have created dynamic dropdown list using this [link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-dynamicstruts/), but when I select some value from available list it should be called in action class.
The dropdown list which can be seen in the image ,here the values are loaded dynamically from the database and now what I want is when I select any value from that two dropdown list that values (I mean text value) should be sent to the action class and there I will execute one JDBC select query on the basis of this two values and will display in the table shown in the image but everything should be on load.Action should be on selecting values from dropdown list not on any button click .With static values I am able to call value from dropdown list into action class with `name` attribute.But in this case I cannot :(
I hope I am clear now .

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried calling select tag using listkey,name and id but none of them worked .
Below is my JSP code:

```xml
<div>
    <div class="invoicetext1">Event Name :</div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <s:select name="dp.eventState" 
                  list="%{state}" 
                 class="billlistbox1" 
                    id="eventName" />   
        <div>
            <s:select name="dp.companyState" 
                     class="billlistbox2"
                   listKey="companyState" 
                      list="%{status}">
            </s:select>
        </div>
        <div class="invoicetext2">Company Name :</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <s:form action="ActionSelect">
        <s:submit value=" Click Here"/>
    </s:form>
<div>
```

Action class for loading dynamic dropdown list :

```
package com.ca.actions;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.ca.database.Database;
import com.ca.pojo.Event;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RetrieveEvNaCoNaAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5418233715172672477L;
    List<Event> dataForBillsJspList;
    private List state = new ArrayList();
    private List status = new ArrayList();
    String eventName;


    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public RetrieveEvNaCoNaAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public List<Event> getDataForBillsJspList() {
        return dataForBillsJspList;
    }

    public void setDataForBillsJspList(List<Event> dataForBillsJspList) {
        this.dataForBillsJspList = dataForBillsJspList;
    }


    public List getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(List status) {
        try {
            Database database = new Database();
            Connection con = database.Get_Connection();

            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT EVENT_NAME,COMPANY_NAME,date_format(FROM_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsFrom,date_format(TO_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsTo FROM EVENT");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            //dataForBillsJspList = new ArrayList<Event>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                /*dataForBillsJspList.add(new Event(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"),
                        rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsFrom"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsTo")));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"));*/
                status.add(rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME")); 

            }
            System.out.println("Data Collected ...");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public List getState() {
        return state;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    setState(this.state);
                    setStatus(this.status);
        return "success";
    }
    public String showEventDetails(){
        System.out.println("Hi.."+eventName);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
    public void setState(List state) {
        //implement the application specific logic to 
        try {
            Database database = new Database();
            Connection con = database.Get_Connection();

            PreparedStatement ps = con
                    .prepareStatement("SELECT EVENT_ID,EVENT_NAME,COMPANY_NAME,CONTACT_PERSON,CONTACT_NO,EMAIL_ID,EVENT_VENUE,date_format(FROM_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsFrom,date_format(TO_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsTo ,EVENT_TIME FROM EVENT");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            dataForBillsJspList = new ArrayList<Event>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                dataForBillsJspList.add(new Event(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"),rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"),
                        rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME"),rs.getString("CONTACT_PERSON"),rs.getString("CONTACT_NO"),rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"),rs.getString("EVENT_VENUE"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsFrom"), rs
                                .getString("dateAsTo"),rs.getString("EVENT_TIME")));
                //System.out.println(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"));
                state.add(rs.getString("EVENT_NAME")); 
                System.out.println(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"));
            }
            System.out.println("Data Collected ...");
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Here for displaying the data on UI, we are using few hardcoded values//
                }
}
```

After loading dynamic dropdown list now i am trying to call selected value in action class by S.O.P but it gives null pointer exception. Below is my POJO class:

```
package com.ca.pojo;

public class Dropdown 
{
    private String eventState;
    private String companyState;
    public Dropdown() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getEventState() {
        return eventState;
    }
    public void setEventState(String eventState) {
        this.eventState = eventState;
    }
    public String getCompanyState() {
        return companyState;
    }
    public void setCompanyState(String companyState) {
        this.companyState = companyState;
    }


}
```

and below is action class where I am trying to call that selected value by using name attribute :

```
package com.ca.actions;

import com.ca.pojo.Dropdown;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class DropdownAction extends ActionSupport 
{
    Dropdown dp;
    public DropdownAction() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Dropdown getDp() {
        return dp;
    }
    public void setDp(Dropdown dp) {
        this.dp = dp;
    }
    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(dp.getEventState());
        return "success";
    }


}
```

struts.xml is properly configured. Now after selecting two values I want to display data in the below table accordingly without any button click but in jsp i have created button just to see whether i am getting the selected value in action class but in actual i want it without any button click.

Comment: Can you 1) Explain EXACTLY what you are trying to do, what is already working and what is not working, and 2) Post some code ?

Comment: I mean by properly editing the question, not in comments. Also when you've done, comment with @AndreaLigios to notify me, if you want me to see it

Comment: First of all thank you @AndreaLigios sir for replying

Comment: I'm still unable to understand what the problem is... nor what you're trying to achieve. You want to search by name, so you need to send the name to the action (or the corresponding id, and in the action retrieve the name using the id): is this that you're not able to do ? If yes, why ? There is no difference between a static `<s:select>` and a dynamic `<s:select>`, the `name` attribute will always point to the same setter in the action. You've lost days on this, then please... stop for a minute, take your time and **describe your problem in a way there could be zero doubts on a reader...**

Comment: Is also not clear if you want to do it classically, with ajax, or if every way is good...

Comment: Basically there is two dropdown list where the values are loaded dynamically. When I call by name attribute in action class I am not able to get any value from the dynamically created list but when I use the same name attribute for the static dropdown list ,I am able to get the value in action class.

Comment: Now what I want to achieve is ..When the user selects values from that dynamically created dropdown list ..page should load data on that basis in the below table ...I am ready to do it by anyway .I dont know ajax since i have never tried my hands on ajax but if you can guide me or provide me some links to my problem related I can study and will try to do it on my own .

Comment: am I clear now sir @AndreaLigios ?

Comment: `When I call by name attribute in action class I am not able to get any value from the dynamically created list` and what do you get ? null, empty list ?

Comment: I get null exception

Comment: Is the second selectbox loaded based on the first selectbox selection ?

Comment: No sir ,they are independent of each other

Comment: Well, post the JSP code of the two selects, the Java code of the getters, and the java code where you read them (only the relevant parts), thanks

Comment: okay sir just wait for 5 minutes ...i will just post everything in my question above

Comment: I have edited my code sir .If any further changes are needed in question please let me know sir :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is a huge mess here :D

First of all, the NullPointerException is thrown because the values are not sent, and the values are not sent because they're not in the form.

You should enclose them in the form like this for them to be sent to the `ActionSelect` action:

```xml
<s:form action="ActionSelect">
    <div class="invoicetext1">Event Name :</div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <s:select name="dp.eventState" 
                  list="%{state}" 
                 class="billlistbox1" 
                    id="eventName" />   
        <div>
            <s:select name="dp.companyState" 
                     class="billlistbox2"
                   listKey="companyState" 
                      list="%{status}">
            </s:select>
        </div>
        <div class="invoicetext2">Company Name :</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <s:submit value=" Click Here"/>
</s:form>
```

Solved the mistery, this doesn't solve your problem, though.

You have two main ways to contact actions from a page:

- Using a standard submit (as you're doing):

  you either submit a form with its content, or call a link by eventually passing parameters in the querystring. This creates a Request, that will contact an action, that will return an entire JSP, that will be loaded in place of the page you're on now.
- Using AJAX:

  you POST or GET to an action without changing the current page, and the action can return anything, like a JSP snippet, a JSON result, a binary result (through the Struts2 Stream result), etc...

  You then can choose what to do with the returned data, for example load it inside a `<div>` that before was empty, or had different content.

Now your problem is that you're contacting an action that is not the one you're coming from (is not able to re-render the entire JSP you're on) and you're calling it without using AJAX, then whatever the object mapped to the `"success"` result is (the whole JSP, or a JSP snippet), it will be loaded in place of the JSP you're on, and it will fail.

Since you seem to be quite new to this, I suggest you start with the easy solution (without AJAX), and after being expert with it, the next time try with AJAX.

That said,

1. avoid putting logic in getters and setters;
2. avoid calling methods that are not setter as setters (`setState`, `setStatus`...);
3. always make your attributes private;
4. try giving speaking names to variables: state and status for event states and company states are really confusing; and what about "state" instead of "name" (in jsp and on DB is "name");
5. consider loading informations like selectbox content in a `prepare()` method, so they will be available also in case of errors;
6. you're not closing the connections (and BTW it would be better to use something more evoluted, like Spring JDBC, or better Hibernate, or even better JPA, but for now keep going with the raw queries)

The following is a refactoring of your code to make it achieve the goal. I'll use `@Getter` and `@Setter` only for syntactic sugar (they're Lombok annotations, but you keep using your getters and setters, it's just for clarity):

```xml
<head>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#event, #company").on('change',function(){
                $("#myForm").submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="myForm">
        <div>
        ...
            <s:select id="event"   name="event"   list="events"    />   
        ...
            <s:select id="company" name="company" list="companies" />   
        ...
        </div>
    </form>

    <div> 
        ...
        Table - iterate **dataForBillsJspList** here    
        ...
    </div>

</body>
```

```java
public class RetrieveEvNaCoNaAction extends ActionSupport {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5418233715172672477L;

    @Getter         private List<Event>     dataForBillsJspList     = new ArrayList<Event>();

    @Getter         private List<String>    events                  = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Getter         private List<String>    companies               = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Getter @Setter private String          event                   = null;
    @Getter @Setter private String          company                 = null;




    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {        
        Connection con;
        try {           
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT company_name FROM event");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) { companies.add(rs.getString("company_name")); }

            // load events
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT event_name FROM event");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) { events.add(rs.getString("event_name")); }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        Connection con;
        try {           
            con = new Database().Get_Connection();

            // load the table. The first time the table is loaded completely
            String sql = "SELECT EVENT_ID, EVENT_NAME, COMPANY_NAME, CONTACT_PERSON, CONTACT_NO, EMAIL_ID, EVENT_VENUE, " + 
                         "date_format(FROM_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsFrom, date_format(TO_DATE,'%d/%m/%Y') as dateAsTo ,EVENT_TIME " + 
                         "FROM event";
            String where = "";

            // if instead this action has been called from the JSP page, 
            // the result is filtered on event and company:
            if (event!=null && company!=null) { 
                where = " WHERE event_name = ? AND company_name = ?"; 
            }

            // load companies
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql + where);
            if (where.length()>0) { 
                ps.setString(1,event); 
                ps.setString(2,company); 
            }
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) { 
                dataForBillsJspList.add(new Event(rs.getString("EVENT_ID"),rs.getString("EVENT_NAME"),rs.getString("COMPANY_NAME"),
                                                  rs.getString("CONTACT_PERSON"),rs.getString("CONTACT_NO"),rs.getString("EMAIL_ID"),
                                                  rs.getString("EVENT_VENUE"), rs.getString("dateAsFrom"), rs.getString("dateAsTo"),
                                                  rs.getString("EVENT_TIME")));
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }

        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

It is a kickoff example, but it should work.

The next steps are:

1. create a POJO with id and description, show the description in the select boxes, but send the id
2. use header values ("please choose an event"...) and handle in action conditional WHERE (only company, only event, both)
3. **PAGINATION**

Good luck

Comment: Thanks alot @AndreaLigios sir . I have started solving my problem by the way which you told me . Thank you once again :)

Comment: I have edited my code sir by your way but i have one doubt i.e whenever I select any two values from that two dropdown list how can my action would be called .How should i configure it in struts.xml ?How should i call my action class ?

Comment: In this kick-off example, the action is always the same, you've already configured it ! In the `execute()` method, an extra operation (the filtering) is performed basing on the parameters coming from the page. If they're not there, it is the first call

Comment: yes sir ,thanks alot I have solved my problem finally..now I am able to select record on the basis of that two values. Thanks alot sir i was stuck in this problem since last 4-5 days and tried alot but everything went in vain :(

Comment: Dose the Lombok work properly in action layer with jsp?

Comment: Yes, but beware of variables one-char-long

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript/jQuery you can do this, it depends on what you want to do after reached action class.

If you want to navigate to another page use the code below.

Add `onchange` event as an attribute to your dropdown,

```
onchange="customFunction(this.value)"
```

create `customFunction` in header part,

```
function customFunction(selectedValue){
     window.location="Action_URL?myValue="+selectedValue;
}
```

Or if you want to return back the same page use [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/),

```
$("#eventName").change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : 'Action_URL',
        data: { myValue: selectedValue},
        success : function(data) {
           alert(data);
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can i do without using javascript or ajax or jquery . I hope there must be some solution .Can you help me with the same sir ?